# É errado ter uma classe só com métodos?

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, classes

É errado ter uma classe só com métodos? Ou seria melhor usar *namespaces* para guardar funções?

Comment: Que vantagens você consegue perceber implementando uma classe somente de métodos ao invés de implementar funções?

Comment: Seria tipo para um jeito para agrupar as funções

Comment: Isto estaria mais para uma consequência que uma vantagem. Criar as funções em um *namespace* teria o mesmo efeito, então com certeza não é uma vantagem. Não entenda mal, mas para obter a resposta certa, você precisa fazer a pergunta certa.  Quando conseguir responder a pergunta anterior, terá o que busca.

Comment: @user8741696 Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Errado é uma palavra muito forte (2).

*Eu irei implementar minhas funções disfarçadas de métodos porque ...*

Se você consegue finalizar esta frase, então é, no mínimo, aceitável fazê-lo. Não há como definir que um código é errado, somente classificá-lo como um código "*cara, por quê fazer assim?*".

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Aliás, a melhor forma de se classificar a qualidade de um código é pela densidade temporal de *wtf*, isto é, quantos *wtf* por minuto o leitor solta ao ler seu código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como o Maniero comentou, já utilizar orientação a objetos em PHP com certeza irá gerar alguns *wtf*. Isso é um tema de discussão bastante comum aqui no site e não é difícil achar os argumentos que defendem tal posição. Porém, se bem utilizado (conscientemente), o número de *wtf* gerado será bem pequeno. Bem como utilizar funções disfarçadas de métodos em uma classe, que, de fato, será um *namespace*, apenas por fazê-lo com certeza irá gerar muitos *wtf*s, pelo simples fato que **não há porquê fazê-lo** (perceba que não digo que é errado, digo que não há motivos em fazê-lo).

Tanto que existem até *frameworks* relativamente conhecidos na comunidade que são implementados inteiramente (ou quase isso) com funções disfarçadas de métodos, a citar [Code Igniter](https://codeigniter.com/). Não significa que ele é bom ou ruim, mas ao fazer isso, terá suas peculiaridades que caberá a você, como desenvolvedor, avaliar se vale a pena ou não utilizá-lo. O mesmo acontece quando você está implementando algo do tipo.

Se você realmente não vê vantagens em utilizar a classe, eu diria para não utilizá-la. Claramente você precisa definir funções e funções existem para isso. Se quer resolver os nomes das funções e evitar qualquer possível conflito, agrupe funções dentro de *namespaces*. Desta forma, pelo menos, você estará mantendo a semântica no seu projeto e deixe classes para quando realmente precisar de classes.

Vale notar também que só o fato de utilizar uma classe não significa que está utilizando orientação a objetos. Esse paradigma vai muito além disso.

Answer (score 4):

Errado é uma palavra muito forte, mas não sei qual a vantagem espera ter em criar um monte de funções em uma classe sem estado.

Eu apenas criaria funções simples. Poderia ser dentro de um *namespace*, faz mais sentido que classes. Nem isso eu faria.

Pra falar a verdade eu já acho estranho usar classes em PHP em quase todos os casos onde elas são usadas, mas sei que minha opinião é controversa, apesar de eu achar que é a única que faz sentido.